# Microsoft Teams Developer Portal - Manually Edit App package Manifest

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a way to manually edit the app package manifest from the Developer Portal in Microsoft Teams, desktop or web?  The editor is set to read-only when viewing the manifest in **Publish > App package > Manifest**.

I would like to do this because there doesn't seem to be a way to create an embedded web view using the **Configure > App Features** in a messaging extension with fetchTask set to false, and providing a taskInfo object like shown below.

```
"composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "261153c9-afc2-4c98-8826-5139e8f5456e",
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "FrankPick",
          "type": "action",
          "title": "Frank Pick",
          "description": "Frank Pick",
          "initialRun": false,
          "fetchTask": false,
          "context": [
            "commandBox",
            "compose"
          ],
           "taskInfo": {
            "title": "Frank Pick",
            "width": "medium",
            "height": "large",
            "url": "https://76a5-97-91-136-36.ngrok.io/JSP2.5/FilePick.html"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You can manually download the app package using Publish > Publish to Store > Download app package - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wez6J.png. After making the necessary edits you can import the package again.